# Android - ViewPager inside a Fragment not using Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment, and I want to have a ViewPager inside of it, but only want part of the page to be a ViewPager, so I'm not making the ViewPager the contentView of the Activity. I'm having a couple problems: I don't know where to "fill in" my view, and I don't know what to do in destoryItem.

Here's what I have (I'm probably missing stuff):

In my Fragment, I am getting the entire fragment layout, and then the ViewPager item from within it, setting the Adapter, the id (not sure if this is needed or what it does), and setting the currentItem.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_how_to_play, parent, false);



    HowToPlayPagerAdapter adapter = new HowToPlayPagerAdapter(getActivity());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.how_to_play_view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);



    return v;
}
```

Still in this Class I have my PagerAdapter, this is where I know there are problems as I am not sure how exactly to implement this.

```
class HowToPlayPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Activity parent;

    public HowToPlayPagerAdapter(Activity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        // TODO: In here I think we'll want to really get the same view every time and just fill it in properly
         return parent.findViewById(R.id.how_to_play_view_pager_id);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mHowToPlayPages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);// No idea what to do in here
    }
}
```

This is my fragment layout where the ViewPager is actually defined.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_header_background_shadowed"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_need2buythis" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/how_to_play_view_pager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the layout for the View I'd like to be inside the ViewPager and then I would fill in the TextView and other elements I'm yet to add depending on which position we're at in the Pager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
   <TextView 
       android:id="@+id/how_to_play_title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
       android:text="Gameplay" />

   <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

Currently when I run it I do see the fragment layout but I see nothing where the ViewPager content should be (no surprise there because I'm not filling in anything with the Text in my current implementation because I don't know where/how to), and when I start just swiping back and forth for a while my app eventually crashes saying I did not override destroyItem.